# How to get cookie value with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting following cookie values on my home page.

> vsettings=HiddenNotifications=%2C19%2C;
>   (referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/;
>   ASPSESSIONIDQCSBCCAD=LFLGDKACEGPCPFGBANHFFBMK;
>   ASPSESSIONIDSASDCCDA=OFEHPJACGHNKICDLFBOCJNNH;
>   ASPSESSIONIDQCSDDCBC=LGFPBDLCKHLIOLPMCAGJNFIM;
>   ASPSESSIONIDQCTACBAC=DCIPJDLCNDBEGEIIELCGFMDP;CustomerID;
>   ASPSESSIONIDSCTCAABD=LHPFFLFDEMIBIENBMGMLFIFP;
>   ASPSESSIONIDSAQDDDAD=HMCDMLFDFCLJCIBHMEHPNHME; s_cc=true;
>   __utmc=97358351; CustomerID=755B031ED8C016EC4F90D6F3127E776AE202DEF5BC6EB9F7A9BB19E49323BC3B;
>   ASPSESSIONIDQCSDBDAC=CFBDJEAAPJJGHMDGOCCHALHC;
>   ASPSESSIONIDSASCBDAD=FLGJHFAAJAJBICGIMOOJEFFF;Session%5FToken=C8F2A63C3BBA4E39BBF73B83C108D1C6

I want get the value of CustomerID cookie.
Using jquery I wrote this:

```
$.cookie('CustomerID',{ path:'/'});
```

But I am not getting the value for cookie - it is showing me blank.

How can I get the CustomerId cookie?

Comment: oh my god please edit the title of that thing.... you want help to the question or to your keyboard ?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is setting a cookie and not getting a cookie.

try `var customerId = $.cookie('CustomerID');`

or maybe you are trying to get the cookie from the root path but it's actually lives at a lower path..

Check out where you save the cookie!

Comment: alert(document.cookie);
var customerId = $.cookie('CustomerID');
alert("value"+customerId);

for document.cookie I am getting values.

But for alert("value"+customerId); I am not getting value.
What I need to do?

Comment: yes I also tried with this:

$.cookie('CustomerID',{ path:'/'});

And I checked CustomerID cookie is on root path.

Comment: show me the code of how you set the value for CustomerID please.