# JQuery Assign a value to a new variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi am using the following jquery code:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

I want to assign the_value to a new variable...

like:

```
var newVar = the_value;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852299/how-to-get-cookie-value-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171865/retrieve-jquery-cookie-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newVar = $.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Answer (score 2):

read the value from cookie

```
var newVar = $.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming i understand your question.

You can add the value from `the_cookie` to a new cookie like `the_cookie_2`
using

```
$.cookie('the_cookie_2', $.cookie('the_cookie'));
```

Or, if you want the cookie value in a variable you can do this

```
var newVar = $.cookie('the_cookie');
```